# I am building a child control application in php and an android app to track the device down?

Tags: php, mysql, json, html, phpmyadmin

Any advice on should I go about linking a parent to certain child a mysql database.
I don't have any code for just yet I would like some more experienced advise.

Comment: Lemme know when you're complete, I need an app to control my child.

Comment: Read this, please http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then ask question provided with  more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ideally you would build this relationship in the following manner:

you have your Parent table with fields: 
PARENT ID
PARENT NAME

then you have your Child table like:
CHILD ID
CHILD NAME

then you have a PARENT-CHILD table like:
PARENT ID
CHILD ID

in this PARENT-CHILD table, each CHILD ID maybe listed combined with 1, or 2 PARENT IDs at the most. A PARENT ID however maybe listed combined with any number of children (hopefully not more than 4, otherwise its not your children than need to be "controlled.")